# How to tell if Serial COM is USB or Bluetooth in Processing?

Tags: java, bluetooth, serial-port, usb, processing

I have a device that can connect via usb and bluetooth, but the ready message that sends to this device varies if it's bluetooth or usb.

The ready message is sent as a byte array where the 2nd element varies, where 0x01 is for USB and 0x02 is for Bluetooth.

```
Serial serial = Serial(s, Serial.list()[0], BAUD_RATE);
byte[] message = new byte[3];
byte[0] = 0x01;
byte[0] = 0x01; // 0x02 for bluetooth
byte[0] = 0x12;
serial.write(message);
```

I want to make my code work dynamically depending on what the user is using, so if usb doesn't work then bluetooth is tested, and if that doesn't work an error message is printed.

I was looking around, but couldn't find any way to detect if the COM port is bluetooth or not in Processing. Is there a reliable way to test for this in Processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Processing Serial library](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/java/libraries/serial/src/processing/serial/Serial.java) doesn't expose any functionality to provide details about the device itself. If you already know the Vendor ID (VID) and Product ID (PID) of these devices, on Windows you can try something [like this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/349002/Select-a-USB-Serial-Device-via-its-VID-PID).

Personally I've used [Python PySerial's ListPortInfo](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo) for related tasks.
If the above code is all the serial code you need to run, you can get away easily with a Python Pyserial script that does both check the port info and write those bytes

If you really really need to use Processing, either look for a Serial or even USB Java library that can provide this info or call Python from Processing via [exec()](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#exec-java.lang.String...-)

Comment: using the C# approach is there a way to detect bluetooth as well?

Comment: In theory, if the Bluetooth Device is setup with SPP ([Serial Port Profile](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bluetooth-basics/all#bluetooth-profiles)), it should show up as a COM/serial port. I'd advise testing first.